# How to assign css for prettify(syntax highlighter)

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting

I used prettify the syntax highlighter in my [blog](http://geeksvijayjobs.blogspot.in/2016/07/hello-world.html) I have achieved what i want is syntax highlighter but i need to adjust the width and also want to stretch the code at some center area.

I have used like this     `"padding: 12px; width: 320px;"`   in this

```
<pre class="prettyprint" style="padding: 12px; width: 320px;">
</pre>
```

But i need to add more perfect way that match the external resources of prettify code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a css class and apply it to the pre element. For example:

css:

```
.blogCodeContainer{
    padding: 12px; 
    width: 320px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<pre class="prettyprint blogCodeContainer">
</pre>
```

Comment: yeah worked but are u sure it wont effect the other parts of code in the template........?

Comment: It should not affect other parts of the code in the template. Also what you can do is to open Chrome inspector (or any browser dev tool) to see exactly what style is being applied and in which order. Hope that helps!